# Adding ViewModel to MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

Working on a small MVC application and I'm trying to implement a ViewModel pattern in the project.  The current architecture is as follows:

View > Controller > Utility Class > Data Provider

The data provider makes a call out to a service and then returns a Response object

```
public class Response
{
     public Response();

     [DataMember]
     public List<CSI.Common.Libraries.Models.SARequest> Requests { get; set;}
}
```

The individual SARequest object:

```
namespace CSI.Common.Libraries.Models
{
    [Serializable, DataContract]
    public class SARequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string AdminUserName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Action { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LegalEntityName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

And then I handle the individual requests for that call in the controller as such:

```
private List<SARequest> GetSARequests()
{
     var requests = CSIAdminUtil.GetSubsidiaryRequests();
     var requestList = requests.Requests;
     return requestList;
}
```

Then I use:

```
@model List<SA Request>
```

on the view with a for loop to display the data.

On the view there are corresponding fields which I would like to allow/disallow editing for based on what action is returned on the request.  So I'm planning on adding attributes to a ViewModel and then setting those based on what action is returned for that request.

I'm not sure on where to start.  I used a VM a long time ago and it seemed like a good way to abstract the logic from the data.  Do I just create the mapping to the ViewModel in the GetSARequests call and then create the view based on a list of SARequestViewModel (the VM I'm planning to use) or do I need to do that in the data provider.

I added automapper to the project, think I have all of the fields correctly.  My question now is, where do I actually convert the model to the viewModel.  I know it sounds simple, just confused at the flow here.

Comment: IMO the former: the data provider should return the "real" data, which gets mapped to and from viewmodels.

Comment: So in the controller

Comment: Sounds sensible, yes.

Comment: Map from the controller context. Your view should be lightweight and focused on ui display facets. Your data layer should only read and write to and from a data store. The closer your view models are to your domain entities in definition, the easier your mapping will be, generally with two lines of mapping code.

Comment: Got it working, way easier than I thought.  There's no way to mark accepted on this anywhere, but thanks Ross and Stuart.